# API method OClass.setCustom fails in distributed environment when trying to write text containing spaces

Tags: orientdb, orientdb3.0

I've implemented an OrientDB client using the Java-API (Version 3.0.30). My code makes heavy usage of custom fields in order to store meta data to schema classes.

In the development and integration test environment everything works fine. In the production environment my initialization method fails at the first `setCustom` command that writes a text containing spaces to a cutom field. The a `OCommandSQLParsingException` is thrown (see below).

In the dev/test environment I'm using all sorts of databases (embedded, plocal and remote access to a standalone OrientDB instance - running on docker).
In the production environment the application connects to a distributed cluster of several OrientDB instances (all docker containers). That's the only difference I can spot.

The initialization code looks like this:

```
try(ODatabaseSession session = orientDbService.getSession()) {
    final String className = "mySuperClass";

    OClass oClass = session.getMetadata().getSchema().getClass(className);
    if(oClass == null) {
        oClass = session.createVertexClass(className);
        oClass.setAbstract(true);
        oClass.setCustom("myDescription", "my superclass");   // <- fails here in production
        oClass.setCustom("myCreationDate", ...
```

The error occors when the text to be written to the custom field contains spaces. Text without spaces is processed without problems.
This exception is thrown:

```
OCommandSQLParsingException: Error parsing query:
alter class `mySuperClass` custom `myDescription`=my superclass
                                                              ^
Encountered " <IDENTIFIER> "superclass "" at line 1, column 53.
Was expecting one of:
  <EOF> 
  <UNSAFE> ...
  ";" ...
  <UNSAFE> ...
  <UNSAFE> ...

  DB name="myDb"
  Error Code="1"
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.parser.OStatementCache.throwParsingException(OStatementCache.java:149)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.parser.OStatementCache.parse(OStatementCache.java:141)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.parser.OStatementCache.get(OStatementCache.java:90)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.parser.OStatementCache.get(OStatementCache.java:68)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLAbstract.preParse(OCommandExecutorSQLAbstract.java:228)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLAlterClass.parse(OCommandExecutorSQLAlterClass.java:60)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLAlterClass.parse(OCommandExecutorSQLAlterClass.java:44)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.parse(OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.java:58)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.parse(OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.java:39)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.distributed.impl.ODistributedStorage.command(ODistributedStorage.java:240)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.OCommandRequestTextAbstract.execute(OCommandRequestTextAbstract.java:68)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.schema.OClassEmbedded.setCustom(OClassEmbedded.java:198)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.schema.OClassEmbedded.setCustom(OClassEmbedded.java:24)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.parser.OAlterClassStatement.executeDDL(OAlterClassStatement.java:318)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.executor.ODDLExecutionPlan.executeInternal(ODDLExecutionPlan.java:55)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.parser.ODDLStatement.execute(ODDLStatement.java:42)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.parser.OStatement.execute(OStatement.java:79)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentEmbedded.command(ODatabaseDocumentEmbedded.java:567)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OConnectionBinaryExecutor.executeQuery(OConnectionBinaryExecutor.java:1188)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.message.OQueryRequest.execute(OQueryRequest.java:136)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary.sessionRequest(ONetworkProtocolBinary.java:310)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary.execute(ONetworkProtocolBinary.java:212)
    at com.orientechnologies.common.thread.OSoftThread.run(OSoftThread.java:69)
```

The following parameters are identical in develop, test and prod environment:

- Version: OrientDB 3.0.30 (Java API, servers)
- Java Runtime: OpenJDK 11
- OS: Linux